# Compass configuration : get sprited icons out of folder

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'd like to have the following tree structure to be sure the folder containing the image files used to build the sprites are not in the same folder as the resulting sprites:

```
.
|
├ images_for_sprite
| ├ sprite-normal
| | ├ icon1.png
| | ├ icon2.png
| | └ iwanttogetinasprite.png
| └ sprite-retina
|   ├ icon1.png
|   ├ icon2.png
|   └ iwanttogetinasprite.png
└ static
  └ images
    ├ sprite-normal-xxxxx.png
    ├ sprite-retina-yyyyy.png
    ├ a_non_sprited_image.jpg
    └ another_one.jpg
```

`static` is the folder that is going to be served by my web server.

**So the point is that I don't want any of `icon1.png`, `icon2.png` or `iwanttogetinasprite.png` in it!**

Maybe `sprite_load_path` is the way to go? But documentation is not clear (or nonexistent) on this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes so it's basically what I guessed:

```
images=static/images
sprite_load_path=images_for_sprite
```